# dialogflow and google sheets API

Tags: api, dialogflow-es

Has anyone done any connection between Dialogflow and Google Sheets API? I need to save user input to a google sheet. Any documentation, examples, experience is appreciated. I am assuming I should connect through a webhook

Comment: I have a great deal of experience - this is what the Vodo Drive action does. Yes, you will need a webhook, you'll need to use Google Sign In or account linking of some sort, and should have some experience with the Sheets API outside of Actions first. StackOverflow works best when you have a specific question or problem, and you've tried to solve it yourself first - if there is something specific we can help you with, you should update the question with as much info as you have. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a sample available on Dialogflow's Github page [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-telephony-nodejs) for some guidance on getting started. According to the [Google Sheets API reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values) and depending on your circumstances, you'll either need to use .append or .update for write operations. A crucial step will be *sharing* the specific sheet with the service account client email address provided to you in the private key json file.